# Suggested Game Engines for beginning game programmer

Tags: c#, c++, game-engine

just curious as to any suggestions for a free game engine I can use to make PC games with, I have been Programming in C++ and C# all through college and internships so I feel very comfortable with either of the languages but have never really explored game developement with the exception of RPGmaker and GameMaker. with that being said I'm looking for an engine/Development tools I can use that  would be the most intuitive/accessible. (please don't say gameMaker or RPGmaker, those are horrible to work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XNA is always a good place to start in my opinion.

There's some pretty cool stuff that's written in XNA:

- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TgChURF5fQE
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OiGADgezjC8

Answer (score 0):

I have done some work with Ogre, which is a c++ library. Not really convivial since it is only a library but powerful enough. There is some good tutorials on their website.